# How to add individual timepoint standard error column to data frame with NaNs (SE of mean of week of timepoints for 24 hours)

Tags: r, nan

I need to create a plot of the body temperatures of mice. I have data points collected every 15 minutes over the course of seven days. I also have the calculated mean temperature at each timepoint for the plot. The next step is calculating the standard error of each of these mean temperatures, taking into account all seven days' worth of temperature readings. This is an image of the extended data I am working from:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmLw3.jpg

I also have a separate, condensed data frame that is the mean_temp from above averaged over seven days for every timepoint, so only one temperature reading each for 24 hours worth of timepoints. It is 96 rows and only contains columns for time and mean_temp24.

With the following code, I am only able to calculate a single standard error for all the timepoints (I know it's wrong but am having a heck of a time finding a solution). I am also unable to calculate standard error from the condensed 24-hour dataset since the full seven days' worth of temperatures are not present.

Adding column with mean temperatures (7 days) of three mice to data frame 'df'
`df=cbind(df,"mean_temp"=rowMeans(df[,3:5],na.rm=TRUE))`

Trying to calculate standard deviation for each timepoint, to start with 
`times = unique(df$time)`

Function to achieve individual standard errors per row

```
for (current_time in times){
df$se=sd(df$mean_temp24, na.rm=T)/sqrt(3-1)
}
```

Ideally, I will end up with a data frame that is 96 lines (each a 15-minute interval timepoint) for 24 hours of temperature data, where the  values are the means of the seven temperatures for each timepoint ("mean_temp" from the image of my data frame). I will also have an additional column for standard error, which takes into account the 7 temperature values used to calculate the mean temperature in the final, 24-hour dataset.

The actual output is a single, identical SE for every timepoint in the full dataset that is not condensed to 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Use ddply from the plyr package. The function f is called for every unique combination of dt and time:

```
f = function(x) {
  n3 = length(which(!is.na(x[,3])))
  n4 = length(which(!is.na(x[,4])))
  n5 = length(which(!is.na(x[,5])))
  data.frame(
    mean3 = mean(x[,3], na.rm=TRUE),
    mean4 = mean(x[,4], na.rm=TRUE),
    mean5 = mean(x[,5], na.rm=TRUE),
    se3 = sd(x[,3], na.rm=TRUE)/sqrt(n3),
    se4 = sd(x[,4], na.rm=TRUE)/sqrt(n4),
    se5 = sd(x[,5], na.rm=TRUE)/sqrt(n5)
  )
}
ddply(df, .(dt,time), f)
```

Comment: Thanks very much, @NielsHolst. I tried applying this to my data and receive this error:  "Error in `[.data.frame`(x, , 4) : undefined columns selected". Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Another query... I am actually using a whole bunch of these sorts of dataset, some with temperature columns for between one and four different mice, as opposed to the sample dataset I provided which has three mice. Is there a way to apply this function to all of them at once (as soon as I get it working), possibly using tapply()?